# Calling a method?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, methods, jtable

okay. I wrote the above code and I need to call it from another class. how can I do it?
plus it gives me this error with `DefaultTableModel prodt = (DefaultTableModel) protable.getModel();`  . the error is non-static variable protable cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public static void refreshProtable() {
    try {
        Statement s1 = Db.connectDb().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE status='" + 0 + "'");

        DefaultTableModel prodt = (DefaultTableModel) protable.getModel();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            Vector v1 = new Vector();
            v1.add(rs1.getString("pid"));
            v1.add(rs1.getString("pname"));
            v1.add(rs1.getString("sp_rt"));
            v1.add(rs1.getString("sp_wh"));
            v1.add(rs1.getString("um"));
            Statement s2 = Db.connectDb().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = s2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE pid='" + rs1.getString("pid") + "'");
            if (rs2.next()) {
                v1.add(rs2.getString("qty"));
            }
            prodt.addRow(v1);
            s2.close();
        }
        s1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag - not only to help others be sure on what language you're working with, it should also allow the syntax highlighter to work correctly on your code.

Comment: Please include the code where you declare protable.

Answer (score 3):

Either mark your variable `protable` static or make the method non-static.

`private static DefaultTableModel protable;`

`public static void refreshProtable() { ... }`

Comment: but I need to call this method from an another class after a button clicked? if I make the method non-static, will I still be able to call it?

Comment: You need to create an instance of that class during the button click and then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is static, you call it using the class name that it is within.

E.g

```
class A {
    public static void b() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Would be called as follows:

```
A.b();
```

It might be handy to refresh yourself on how static variables work, here would be a starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to make `protable` as static as you can access only static variables from a static method.

```
private static DefaultTableModel protable;

public static void refreshProtable() { }
```

the variable you are trying to call is an instance-level variable;

**static variable**

- It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance)
- Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution . These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables
- A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
- A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object
- Syntax : .

**static method**

- It is a method which belongs to the class and not to the object(instance)
- A static method can access only **static** data. It can not access non-static data (instance variables)
- static method can call only other static methods and can not call a non-static method from it.
- A static method can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object
- Syntax : .
- A static method cannot refer to “this” or “super” keywords in anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can make your function as non-static or make protable object static.

In a word, you can not reference non-static variable in static function.

but you can reference static variable in non-static function